# Delete a MS Word Page using macros

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

How can I delete certain page from MS Word document using macros? The code should be compatible from 2000 to Word 2010.

I've tried using page bookmark to delete page but, output is varying in different versions. Is there any other solution than this?

Comment: Have you a standard first and last sentence?

Comment: Nope. There is no standard First and Last statement.

Comment: How is the "certain" page determined then. Or is it a popup asking the user *Please enter the page you want to delete*

Comment: There is a logic in place which moves to next page based on some mathematical calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with whole pages can be a pain because of pagination. You'll need to make sure that you've got the document paginated first. Then you should be able to use the Document.GOTO function to jump to a specific page. At that point, you'll have to iterate down until the INFO object tells you you've moved to the next page or the end of the doc. At that point you know the start and end of the page and should be able to create a RANGE to delete it.

Finally, some of those functions (like the info object) can be finicky and will only work in specific VIEW modes (like print preview, vs draft), so you may have to save the current view mode, change it, then change it back when you're done.